# There are any ActionBar visibility change event listeners

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I'm designing a backdrop design. When I hide an action bar then the front layout needs to change its position, so I need to detect ActionBar visibility. Are there any layout changes or events that can used to be do that?

Comment: You intentionally hide the action bar, so why you need a listener for that

Comment: to change a front layout position

Comment: @Zain means you can change front layout position when you intentionally `actionBar` hide simultaneously. So you don't need listener.

Answer (score 2):

Implement `ActionBar.OnMenuVisibilityListener` interface in your listener class.

Write responses in `@Override public void onMenuVisibilityChanged(boolean isVisible) {... }`

Register listener in ActionBar with `ActionBar.addOnMenuVisibilityListener(obj)`

Answer (score 2):

`ActionBar.OnMenuVisibilityListener`

You can use this method for your work. For more details you can check here:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar.OnMenuVisibilityListener